# Days since rolling 52-week high in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

EDIT: Just when I gave up i found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734763/using-pandas-to-find-the-number-of-periods-since-the-rolling-high):

```
rmlag = lambda xs: np.argmax(xs[::-1])
df['Open'].rolling(window=5).apply(func=rmlag)
```

I'm wrestling with the following issue: How can i add a column to a DataFrame that, for each row, calculates the number of days (periods) since an n-period high was reached?

Below is a sample DataFrame i'm working with. I've calculated the rolling 5-day high as

```
 df['Rolling 5 Day High'] = df['Open'].rolling(5).max()
```

How can I calculate, for each row, the number of days since the respective 5-day high was reached? For example, the "Number of Days Since" for the row indexed at 2012-03-16 should be 4 since this row's corresponding rolling 5-day high of 14.88 was reached on 2012-03-12. For the next row at index 2012-03-19, the value should be 3 given this row's rolling 5-day high of 14.79 was reached on 2012-03-14.

```
             Open  Rolling 5 Day High
Date
2012-03-12  14.88                 NaN
2012-03-13  14.65                 NaN
2012-03-14  14.79                 NaN
2012-03-15  14.41                 NaN
2012-03-16  14.59               14.88
2012-03-19  14.68               14.79
2012-03-20  14.56               14.79
2012-03-21  14.40               14.68
2012-03-22  14.35               14.68
2012-03-23  14.40               14.68
2012-03-26  14.69               14.69
2012-03-27  14.78               14.78
2012-03-28  15.01               15.01
2012-03-29  15.14               15.14
2012-03-30  15.36               15.36
2012-04-02  15.36               15.36
2012-04-03  15.44               15.44
2012-04-04  14.85               15.44
2012-04-05  14.67               15.44
2012-04-09  14.40               15.44
2012-04-10  14.38               15.44
2012-04-11  14.35               14.85
2012-04-12  14.36               14.67
2012-04-13  14.55               14.55
2012-04-16  14.26               14.55
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pandas To Find the Number Of Periods Since the Rolling High](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734763/using-pandas-to-find-the-number-of-periods-since-the-rolling-high)

Comment: Great question.  In your answer, could you elaborate a little more on how you set this up as a new column ie. "days since 5 day high" in the dataframe ?   Maybe post the whole thing as an answer also.